# Skype message history

Tags: skype

Edit: I had my skype hacked and then restored password by email. Is it possible that my message history was downloaded and what if it contains some password?

Answer (score 0):

If the hacker had file access to your PC, then all of your history can be seen.

However, this is likely not the case. They would be able to see recent history ([30 days](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA392/where-can-i-find-my-conversation-history-in-skype-for-windows-desktop-and-what-can-i-do-with-it)), as much as can be downloaded when Skype is first logged in. The full history is not available to be downloaded, and is stored on your computer.